# Session manipulated client side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, session, client-server

I'm trying to program a check off calendar/task app.
Want I want to achieve is that, whenever I click on a box it should be checked off, show it's crossed off ( [Day is crossed off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO5eb.png) ).
And then I want to store this is in my session.

What I'm thinking about doing is setting a boolean variable in the HTML to true and then send it with the session. So it can be remembered when I reload the page. But I still see the problem of letting the server-side know that this boolean has changed. 
Is this the way to achieve this? Is there some better way?

Controlling my server-side is Nodejs and I'm using the ejs templating. I'm using express-session to manage my session.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you @tacoshy! I'll see if I can be more specific about my question. My thing is that I want to make a change client side which get stored in the session. So when I reload the page that change I made client side is remembered, when my server side is reloading the page. The data/session server-side is handled by express-session.
I'll read the tour and the guide to questions!

Comment: I solved this by adding a fetch with a post method to the client side.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.